# Cos'è un "tarlocco"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> Ma non possiamo continuare a star qui ad aspettare per delle ore sul ballatoio tu e io come due **tarlocchi**. Senti, io guardo se riesco a buttar giù la porta con qualche spallata.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è un "tarlocco"? Non l'ho trovato su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Si tratta di un termine di uso regionale (forse lombardo)?

Comment: Qui: https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=vxr-001:1975:34::378 (pagina 76) gli si dà il significato di «stolido, strambo, balordo» e lo si considera un termine dell’italiano settentrionale. Qui: http://bpfe.eclap.eu/eclap/axmedis/6/617/00000-617dd2d3-88f6-4cf3-a456-846417dad281/2/~saved-on-db-617dd2d3-88f6-4cf3-a456-846417dad281.pdf (su Mistero Buffo) gli si dà il significato di «stupido».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il termine da cercare è ***[tarlucco](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000748.jpg)*** che, come riporta il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, significa:

> **Tarlucco**,  agg. (plur. m. 
>   -*chi*).  Region. Stupido, alloc­co, tonto, sciocco. – Anche sostant. 
>       
>   *Sbarbaro*,   I-650:  Zitti,  zitti!  /  più  bevuto  /  d’un  imbuto, 
>   /  barcollando,  /  come  un  bove  gorgheggiando,  /  il  tarlucco 
>   ma­ledetto  [il  Ciclope]  /  dal  suo  tetto  /  avanza  il  piè. 
>   *Eco*,   14-11:  Giuda  impestato,  io  sono  sempre  quello  che  si 
>   fa  far  su  come  un  tarlucco,  roba  che  mi  darei  i  pugni 
>   nella  testa  ancor  oggi,  toh, così! 
>       =  Voce  di  area  sett.  (cfr.  genov.  *tarlûcco*,   milan.  *tarlucch*,   piemont.  *tarlüch*),  deriv. dal provenz.  *trelucà*  ‘insensato’.

Answer (score 0):

A quanto sembra la parola tarlocco in italiano attualmente non esiste se non come neologismo dialettale simile a "martalotto", "tarlùc" in dialetto milanese, che viene rivolta a chi è in difficoltà nell'apprendere, "dicasi duro di comprendonio", praticamente un tontolone, imbranato. Sperando di essere stato d'aiuto.
Un cordiale saluto.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!!

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @Luke, ma cosa sono "neologismo dialettale" e "martalotto"? E quello che stai spiegando proviene da qualche fonte?